# Создание голограмм

Tags: графика

Давно хотел сделать что-то на подобии голограммы. Т.е. какое-нибудь изображение, которое будет показываться не на экране монитора, а в реальном пространстве. Кто знает, где можно почитать на эту тему, какой язык программирования и среду можно использовать и вообще, что для этого нужно?

Comment: Поясните подробнее, где и как вы хотите сделать =) По-моему, это инженерная задача, а не программирования. Выбор оборудования и всё такое... Или вы про всякие стереопары?)

Comment: Мне просто нужно узнать что для этого можно использовать, есть ли какие-нибудь написанные библиотеки. И кто занимается этим вообще.

Если есть что-нибудь про стереопары, то тоже было бы неплохо кинуть пару ссылок.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос непонятен. Голограмма - это когда на специальную подложку лазером записывается интерференционная картинка. С информацией об амплитуде и фазе волны...
И нет такого дисплея на коем её можно воспроизвести - плотность пикселов чересчур низкая. Посему я не понимаю, как это связано с программированием и что за SDK можно посоветовать)

Да стереопары - просто две картинки снятые с двух разных, но близких точек (как глаза у человека расположены). В 3D это реализовать просто - две виртуальных камеры, с каждой брать своё изображение.

[Реализация настоящего 3D эффекта в своих проектах](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/3d_graphics/115031/) - вот вводная статья.

Как уже делать это в программе, если требуется это, - смотрите SDK по OpenGl или DirectX. Или ещё по чему=)